# Create new columns based on distinct row values and calculate frequency of every value

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I would like to extract all distinct row values from specific columns and create new columns and calculate their frequency in every row.

My Input Dataframe is:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'user_id': ['abc','def','ghi'],
   'alpha': ['A','B,C,D,A','B,C,A'],
   'beta': ['1|20|30','350','376']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['user_id','alpha','beta'])
print(df)
```

Looks like this,

```
     user_id   alpha      beta
0     abc        A     1|20|30
1     def  B,C,D,A         350
2     ghi    B,C,A         376
```

I want something like this,

```
  user_id    alpha     beta  A  B  C  D  1  20  30  350  376
0     abc        A  1|20|30  1  0  0  0  1   1   1    0    0
1     def  B,C,D,A      350  1  1  1  1  0   0   0    1    0
2     ghi    B,C,A      376  1  1  1  0  0   0   0    0    1
```

My original data contains 11K rows. And these distinct values in alpha & beta are around 550.

I created a list from all the values in alpha & beta columns and applied `pd.get_dummies` but it results in a lot of rows. I would like all the rows to be rolled up based on user_id.

A similar idea is used by `CountVectorizer` on documents, where it creates columns based on all the words in the sentence and checks the frequency of a word. However, I am guessing Pandas has a better and efficient way to do that.

Grateful for all your assistance. :)

Desired Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Series.str.get_dummies` to create a dummy indicator dataframe for each of the columns `alpha` and `beta` then using `pd.concat` concat these dataframes along `axis=1`:

```
cs = (('alpha', ','), ('beta', '|'))
df1 = pd.concat([df] + [df[c].str.get_dummies(sep=s) for c, s in cs], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
print(df1)

  user_id    alpha     beta  A  B  C  D  1  20  30  350  376
0     abc        A  1|20|30  1  0  0  0  1   1   1    0    0
1     def  B,C,D,A      350  1  1  1  1  0   0   0    1    0
2     ghi    B,C,A      376  1  1  1  0  0   0   0    0    1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shubham for editing and providing a solution.. Can you explain `code` cs = (('alpha'..... '|')) line please...

Comment: @Sasha18 Sure..`Series.str.get_dummies` require `sep` as a optional parameter, each string in series is split by  this `sep` ... As  `alpha` contains the separator `,` while beta contains the separator `|` so in order to provide `sep` to `get_dummies` method inside a list comprehension we create `tuple` pairs of `column, sep` for simplicity..